# showing XML result as an array in component

Tags: xml, angular, typescript

i have a problem concerning xml response from the httpclient GET method. 
i want to show the response as column : value 
for example : `<tarif>100</tarif>` the result i want to show is `tarif:100` in my html.

how can i do that. i tried to do the foreach with a lot of code, and it worked but i think there is a better  solution to do that.

here is my code in my component :

```
this.http.get('http://website.com?' + contenu, { responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe(response  =>  this.contenuResult = response);
```

in my html i have a text from the response like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tarification><numdem>25322733</numdem><code>1</code></tarification>
```

how can i get in my html something like this :

```
numdem: 25322733
code: 1
```

Thank you call for your help ^^

Comment: Have you tried with responseType: text/xml. What happens to the response then? How does it look?

Comment: i already tried it but no its doesn't work. it give me an error : Type '"text/xml"' is not assignable to type '"json"

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a json of the xml. Then you can access it as an object i your components

```
function parseXml(xmlStr) {
    let result;
    var parser = require('xml2js');
    parser.Parser().parseString(xmlStr, (e, r) => {result = r});
    return result;
}
```

xml2js should be built in in angular-cli

ex:

```
.subscribe(response  =>  this.contenuResult = this.parseXml(response));
```

But if it works. You cant do this all the time so either you wrap the httpClient or create a base service.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. i have an error i don't even understand  ERROR ReferenceError: "global is not defined"

Comment: Yes you need to install: npm install xml2js --save. Its not built in I as I thought. But it should be enough to intall only that

Comment: npm install rxmjs2 in my case didn't get me the timers and the stream. thats why i needed to install them both separatedly. thank you for your help my friend @jens Alenius

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution,

in my component :

```
    sendToWebService(contenu) {


    return this.http.get('http://www.tarif_xml.php?' + contenu, {responseType: 'text'})

      .subscribe(response => this.contenuResult = this.parseXml(response));
  }

  parseXml(xmlStr) {
    const parser = require('xml2js').parseString;
    parser(xmlStr, function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

you must also install rxmljs and stream, timers with angular-cli

and you must put this code in your index.html :

```
 <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
```